# Why does this PDE have a solution?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, elliptic-pde, surfaces

Let $\Sigma$ be a compact surface and denote by $\nu$ the unit conormal for $\partial \Sigma$. Let

$$E = \left\{ \phi \in C^{2,\alpha}(\Sigma) : \int_{\Sigma} \phi \, \mathrm{d}A = 0 \right\} $$
and
$$F = \left\{ \phi \in C^{0,\alpha}(\Sigma) : \int_{\Sigma} \phi \, \mathrm{d}A = 0 \right\},$$

for fixed $0 < \alpha < 1$.

I would like to know why, given $(f,h) \in F \times C^{1,\alpha}(\partial \Sigma)$, the problem

$$\begin{cases} -\Delta_{\Sigma} u = f + \frac{1}{\vert \Sigma \vert} \int_{\partial \Sigma} h \, \mathrm{d}L, \quad \text{on } \Sigma \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu} = -h, \quad \text{on } \partial \Sigma
\end{cases}$$

has a solution in $E$. This came up for me in [this paper, page 8](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.6257.pdf). I am sorry if the question is silly, but I am not very good at PDE's.

Comment: This came up in *which* paper?

Comment: Is $\Sigma$ a free-boundary, or is it not? In the latter case you are just solving a Neumann problem on a domain; the fact that $\Sigma$ is a surface in $M^3$ is not that relevant. (Also, probably not a good idea to use $g$ both as the ambient metric and the boundary Neumann data.) If $\Sigma$ is a free-boundary (as you stated in the question), then things could get complicated.

Comment: crossposted - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3298263/existence-of-solution-to-this-pde